# How to access private members of a class by another class without using friend class

Tags: c++, inheritance

Suppose we have the following:

```
class base{
}

class derived1 : public base{
  private:
  void fun();
  friend class derived2;
}

class derived2 : public base{
  derived1 ob;
  void fun2(){
  ob->fun();
}
```

I want to use fun() of derived1 in derived2's fun2() wihtout using friend class and keeping fun() private in derived1.

Comment: The whole point of it being private is that you're not supposed to be able to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure whether it is a viable work around for you, but here it is:

```
class base{
   public:
   virtual void fun() {}
};

class derived1 : public base{
  private:
  void fun() {}
};

class derived2 : public base{
  derived1 ob;
  void fun2(){
  static_cast<base&>(ob).fun();
  }
};
```